# Dynamic populate dropdown doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fill a dropdown list dynamically but it doesn't work. here is the code:

```
<form id="email-compose" class="form-email-compose" method="get" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select id="input-to" class="input-transparent form-control">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="input-subject" placeholder="Subject" class="input-transparent form-control"
               value="<%= subject %>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea rows="10" class="form-control" id="wysiwyg" placeholder="Message"><%- body %></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="btn-toolbar pull-xs-right">
            <button type="reset" id="compose-discard-button" class="btn btn-gray">Annuler</button>
            <button type="submit" id="compose-send-button" onClick="sendMail()" class="btn btn-danger">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Envoyer&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and the corresponding JS:

```
var jsonData = {
  "Table": [{
      "stateid": "2",
      "statename": "Texas"
  }, {
      "stateid": "3",
      "statename": "Louisiana"
  }, {
      "stateid": "4",
      "statename": "California"
  }, {
      "stateid": "5",
      "statename": "Nevada"
  }, {
      "stateid": "6",
      "statename": "Massachusetts"
  }]
};

 $(document).ready(function () {
     var listItems = '<option selected="selected" value="0">- Select -</option>';

  for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.Table.length; i++) {
         listItems += "<option value='" + jsonData.Table[i].stateid + "'>" + jsonData.Table[i].statename + "</option>";
     }
    console.log(listItems);
     $("#input-to").html(listItems);
 });
```

If I insert manually the option tags, I can see them correctly in the select but not dynamically...
I also tried with .append method but still having an empty drop down list.

Any idea ?

EDIT 1:

I also tried to use .append like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#input-to').append('<option selected="selected" value="0">- Select -</option>');
for (var i = 0,opt; opt= jsonData.Table[i]; ++i) {
    $('#input-to').append('<option value="' + opt.stateid + '">' + opt.statename + '</option>');
}
});
```

but same thing, my dropdown remains empty...
No problem of syntax as if I add manually the options I can see the options available.

one additional thing, my form is surrounded by a script:

```
<script type="text/template" id="compose-view-template">
....<form>
</script>
```

with the following js

```
        var ComposeView = Backbone.View.extend({


        template: _.template($('#compose-view-template').html()),

        attributes: {
            id: 'compose-view',
            class: 'compose-view'
        },

        events: {
            "click #compose-save-button, #compose-send-button, #compose-discard-button": 'backToFolders'
        },

        render: function() {
            $('#widget-email-header').html(
                '<h5>Nouvel <span class="fw-semi-bold">Email</span></h5>'
            );
            $('#folder-stats').addClass('hide');
            $('#back-btn').removeClass('hide');
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            this._initViewComponents();


            return this;
        },

        backToFolders: function(){
            App.showEmailsView();

        },

        _initViewComponents: function(){
            this.$("textarea").wysihtml5({
                html: true,
                customTemplates: bs3Wysihtml5Templates,
                stylesheets: []
            });
        }
    });
```

may be the js function is called when the form is not completely created ? hence, there is no action (and no error) because the form is not completely created ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your making a small mistake in your code

See the commeted out code below:

```
 var jsonData = {
  "Table": [{
      "stateid": "2",
      "statename": "Texas"
  }, {
      "stateid": "3",
      "statename": "Louisiana"
  }, {
      "stateid": "4",
      "statename": "California"
  }, {
      "stateid": "5",
      "statename": "Nevada"
  }, {
      "stateid": "6",
      "statename": "Massachusetts"
  }]
};

 $(document).ready(function () {
     //
     // Since your are adding the html to the element
     // You dont need to recreate it!
     //

     //  var listItems = '<option selected="selected" value="0">- Select -
     //  </option>';
     var listItems="";

  for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.Table.length; i++) {
         listItems += "<option value='" + jsonData.Table[i].stateid + "'>" + jsonData.Table[i].statename + "</option>";
     }
    console.log(listItems);
     $("#input-to").html(listItems);
 });
```

Here is a fiddle of a working version

https://jsfiddle.net/40zz77ex/

Comment: I tried to change listITems delcaration but same result. notice that listItems is correctly filled with the different options and if I copy/paste the option manuall in the select, I can see the different choices in the dropdown list

Comment: If you see my answer your see if have added a link to jsfiddle where you can view a working version of the code. The code runs no errors and displays the states in the drop down as expected  - can you accept the answer as correct - thank you.

Comment: sorry but even if your proposal is working, when I integrate it in mi code it doens't work....

Comment: My proposal fixed the issue you posted in the Question. The reason why it won't work in your code is because you have more errors in other parts of your code that I have not seen. When you run your code it breaks in the console with an error that error stops my code above from running. Hence your code does not work. You need to learn how to find bugs in your code. To start open the browser dev console, and look for errors - they are listed in bright red. Any typo of bug in your code can prevent all your code from running.

Comment: MartinWebb, thanks for your advice but I know how to debug my code....If I'm asking some help is because I tried multiple cases, and I would need a second view and expertise on jquery, not on debug as I do not have any error....

Comment: Sorry. The code you gave me as per my edits works correctly. That is this problem solved so you should mark this answer as correct. If you have more code and this code within that code does not work. Sadly you need to ask another question. I can't fix a problem i can't see.

Comment: The question seems to have changed with more code. If your form is wrapped in a script tag it wont work.

Comment: And now seems to have changed into a backbone app. This is a joke and the question should be removed and proposed correctly.

Comment: you're right MartinWebb, this code is using a backbone but I never used it, just retrieved the code from a template. but quite strange that a simple append is not working isn't it ?

Comment: No its not strange.

Comment: As i said your question has changed and the title content of the question is not what it was, the answer was given, and the answer made the code you posted work, fixing the bug. The problem you now have is a completely different one. And i'm not going to waste more time fixing the new problem. Resolve the original issue. And ask a new question with backbone in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.append` instead of building HTML string. Something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#input-to').append('<option selected="selected" value="0">- Select -</option>');
    for (var i = 0,opt; opt= jsonData.Table[i]; ++i) {
        $('#input-to').append('<option value="' + opt.stateid + '">' + opt.statename + '</option>');
    }
});
```

**See working example**

```js
var jsonData = {
  "Table": [{
    "stateid": "2",
    "statename": "Texas"
  }, {
    "stateid": "3",
    "statename": "Louisiana"
  }, {
    "stateid": "4",
    "statename": "California"
  }, {
    "stateid": "5",
    "statename": "Nevada"
  }, {
    "stateid": "6",
    "statename": "Massachusetts"
  }]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input-to').append('<option selected="selected" value="0">- Select -</option>');
  for (var i = 0, opt; opt = jsonData.Table[i]; ++i) {
    $('#input-to').append('<option value="' + opt.stateid + '">' + opt.statename + '</option>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="input-to"></select>
```

Comment: Did you load `jquery.js`? `$` requires `jquery` loaded before it.

Comment: Alex, it makes me crazy....yes your code is working, but when I integrate it there is nothing happening...no error, just an empty dropdown....I used to work with JQuery but as that time I don't know why neither append nor html have no effect....may be the form is not completely created when I try to fill with options ?

Comment: Populate the dropdown from `render` function.

Comment: If you have surround the html form in a script tag it won't work. This questions seems to have made many twists and turned from the original question. The OP needs to give us all the code and be clear. The original question was fixed in my answer.